# How to merge with upstream repo

Tags: git

Im working on a project on a forked repo and when I want to merge with upstream it doesnt seem to delete the files that have been deleted on the upstream repo. They still exist at mine locally but I want to take all the changes that have been made on the upstream repo. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the commands you are using.. their outputs, etc?

Comment: git fetch upstream and then git merge upstream/sandbox 
it lets me merge but it doesnt remove the files from the original branch

Comment: In a project I collaborate, I use git fetch upstream, and then **git rebase upstream/sandbox**. Try to see if it works for you.

Comment: Have you modified the deleted files on your branch? This could prevent them from getting deleted, though you'd likely get merge conflicts at the time of merge.